# Class Design for JPA Entities with Multiple Tables Referring to Same Business Object

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, database-design, jpa

I have an application that works with products from various external data sources (in DataSourceProduct) and it also maintains its own version of the product (in MasterProduct). Here's the DB schema:

[image: DB Schema]

Note: DataSourceProduct has ten other columns not shown in the diagram. The MasterProduct has ten other columns not shown in the diagram. For example These column have the same name in each table.  that have the same name but for brevity are not shown in the diagram. The common columns are not on the Product table but are on the DataSourceProduct

Each external data source may provide its own representation of a given product. The productId (i.e. Product.id) is an auto generated (incrementing) id in the database. It's a surrogate key. A productId should refer to 1 & only 1 real world product. Each data source may have its own data about that product and the DB must capture that. Suppose we have an iron door. If it's the first product inserted into the DB it will be given a productId of 1. Now, data source A may give a description of "fine door". Data source B may give the same iron door a description of "old iron door". So, DataSourceProduct will have 2 rows (1 row for each data source). Both rows will have productId = 1 so that we can know that the both data sources are actually referring to the same product.

Unfortunately, there is no data (such as SKU) that can determine that a product from data source A and data source B refer to the same product. Users will manually map the products as being the same. The Product table's productId serves the purpose of storing the user mapping (i.e. id which products from various data sources are referring to the same product).

The application also needs to have its own version of product data which is stored in the MasterProduct table. It differs from DataSourceProduct because

1. It must maintain history of data changes to a product
2. It must maintain vendor data

The application's product (i.e. MasterProduct) will be used extensively throughout the application whereas the external data source's product (i.e. DataSourceProduct) is only used in one small part of the application.

How should I design the corresponding JPA entities? The three tables representing products may (?) make sense from a DB perspective. In OOP though, it seems like an inheritance relationship exists.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  What does the productID value actually signify here?  Are you saying that a single product can have multiple productID values depending on which description is used?

Comment: Are the common fields of the product located in *Product* table? Or It's just a table for relationships? For the second case it',s just unecessary because It looks like a one-to-one relationship. The name also could lead to confusion.

Comment: @Andrew, the productId is an auto generated (incrementing) id in the database. It's a surrogate key. A productId should refer to 1 & only 1 real world product. Each data source may have its own data about that product and the DB must capture that. Suppose we have an iron door. If it's the first product inserted into the DB it will be given a productId of 1. Now, data source A may give a description of "fine door". Data source B may give the same iron door a description of "old iron door". So, DataSourceProduct will have 2 rows (1 row for each data source). Both rows will have productId = 1.

Comment: @Laiv, it's the second case. But it's not a one-to-one relationship. A product can be represented by many different data sources. A data source product represents one product. So, it's a one to many relationship.

Comment: @James Then I would change the name to the table because It's confusing. It's rather a SKU than a Product. Also many-to-one relationship can be implemented with two tables only. The table Product, IMO, is adding complexity to the model.

Comment: @James I'm not sure I agree with Laiv about condensing to two tables.  It seems that the DataSourceProduct table (which may be misnamed) embodies the *relationship* between the dataSource and the Product.  I assume the product table contains many other details about the product, other than the DataSource-associated name?  Anyway I would probably create objects for each of these tables and define the relationships between them using JPA notation.  I don't see much inheritance since they each contain their own relevant fields -- which is probably why you should rename.

Comment: For example the MasterProduct table seems more like a ProductHistory table, which *includes* a product plus a lot more data.  I'm not sure how it has a relationship to the vendor, though, since as you said it also includes product history.  It should relate to some kind of *Transaction* object, which in turn might relate to a Vendor, or might just be a note on product updates.

Comment: @Andrew, I also agree that three tables seem appropriate to represent the `Product`, `DataSource` and the many-to-many relationship between `Product` and `DataSource` (in the OP named `DataSourceProduct`). From Laiv's comment though I thought it may be aid clarity to rename `Product` to `SKU`. To answer your question, the `Product` table only contains the auto-generated `id`. `DataSourceProduct` does contain may details about a product per a data source's record of that product.

Comment: @James it's generally poor design to have a table with only one row -- if nothing else you can include date fields to show when the product was created, modified, etc. , and perhaps a simple description or name to make it human-readable?  Also, to be clear, the combination of productId and dataSource is unique in the DataSourceProduct table?

Comment: @Andrew, Did you mean that is is generally poor design to have a table with only one **column**? I'm assuming you are referring to the `Product` table. If so, I have doubts about adding columns for "human readability". You can always join the `Product` table to other tables to get product information per the internal and various external data sources. You are correct in regards to your second question about uniqueness in the `DataSourceProduct` table.

Comment: @James right, that's what I meant.  Although it's also bad to have only one row.  Point is that a table is meant to store data.  If there's no data, why create the table just to store one value that's not independently meaningful?  Although there is some disagreement about this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951686/is-a-one-column-table-good-design), in this case I'm not sure I see the utility.

Comment: @James but it's beside the point.  After all you can always add more columns later if it becomes useful.

Comment: Just an advice when using ORM the wrong approach is design first the RDBM and then the entities. It's just the opposite. Forget your current design and start by the classes and then move to the db.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion stems from the Product table's general lack of utility, since it contains an ID and nothing else.

However it's not a big deal.  When defining JPA entities, I would start with the Products table and define each of the child objects as separate classes.  Then include those in the Product class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
   List<DataSourceProduct> dataSourceProducts;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
   List<MasterProduct> masterProducts;
}
```

Each of these child products would be define with the reverse @ManyToOne relationship with the Product table.

As you mention in the comments, you might rename these and maybe shift around some of the properties, but I think this structure should be a good starting point.